# Question completely disappearing

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Yesterday there was a question which I answered, and the answer got  two downvotes, so I tried to understand what I was not communicating well. The question was about "energy conservation appearing because of field theory". There were a number of comments to my answer by AccidentalFourierTransform and,I think, GenaroTedesco . Thinking it over before going to sleep, I planned to edit my answer to make clear that the energy conservation law applies to closed systems. When I entered this morning, greek time,the whole thing has disappeared. As a high reputation user I see deleted questions by anybody. This has disappeared completely and not edited to a new format afaik.

Whats up? For us senior citizens where the A possibility looms, it is disturbing to have to start thinking "did I really answer the question, or did I think I did " (joking at the moment as I still have all my faculties intact, but time flies).

Comment: Click QMechanics [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+deleted%3Ayes), there you will see your own deleted posts (because you have far more as the required 10000 reputation for that). Order the list as "newest", so you will see your last deleted posts. Your post will somewhere in the list. If you click it, you will see who is deleted it. If you are now shocked, how many good posts were here deleted, you aren't alone. Although the same problem exists not only on the PSE, rather everywhere on the SE network, on all sites.

Answer (score 8):

I) In the specific case, the asker deleted the specific [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/352328/2451) (and thereby any answer in its thread).

II) More generally,

- All users can *not* see deleted items in their own profile page listings, except for the last 60 days by clicking "deleted recent questions/answers".
- 10k+ users can view any deleted post if they have the post's URL.
- 10k+ users can search for their [own deleted posts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+deleted%3Ayes) but not other's.
- 10k+ users can browse recently deleted questions from the last 30 days on their
  [mod tools](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete).

Comment: Is it true that "Recently Deleted Questions" will only be kept for 60 days at most in the user profile? Then it will be permanently deleted? Thank you!

Comment: No, a so-called deleted post is permanently visible to owner & 10k users if they have the URL.

Comment: But it will not be found in the "Recently Deleted Questions" in the user profile? (Most people will not keep the URL permanently.) So I wonder whether the Deleted Question will be kept in the user profile. Thank you!

Comment: $\uparrow$ Right.

Comment: Thanks! How about the closed question? Will it stay in my profile or it will get removed from my profile?